# How I can to validate my Junit test with Gson parse

Tags: java, json, junit, gson

I'm using the Gson library and jakarta. Although I have been able to use the conversion in CarrinhoResource.java as below, my ClienteTest.java cannot use the String content (already in json) inside the cart. I cant run my test a just only message into my intellij is (Cannot resolve method 'fromJson(java.lang.String)').
Can someone help me?

```
Class CarrinhoResource.java
package br.com.alura.loja.resource;

import br.com.alura.loja.dao.CarrinhoDAO;
import br.com.alura.loja.modelo.Carrinho;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/v1/carrinhos")
public class CarrinhoResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String busca(){
      Carrinho carrinho = new CarrinhoDAO().busca(1L);
    return carrinho.toJson();
    }
}


Carrinho.java
package br.com.alura.loja.modelo;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class Carrinho {

    private List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<Produto>();
    private String rua;
    private String cidade;
    private long id;

    public Carrinho adiciona(Produto produto) {
        produtos.add(produto);
        return this;
    }

    public Carrinho para(String rua, String cidade) {
        this.rua = rua;
        this.cidade = cidade;
        return this;
    }

    public Carrinho setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getRua() {
        return rua;
    }

    public void setRua(String rua) {
        this.rua = rua;
    }
    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }
    
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void remove(long id) {
        for (Iterator iterator = produtos.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Produto produto = (Produto) iterator.next();
            if(produto.getId() == id) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void troca(Produto produto) {
        remove(produto.getId());
        adiciona(produto);
    }

    public void trocaQuantidade(Produto produto) {
        for (Iterator iterator = produtos.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Produto p = (Produto) iterator.next();
            if(p.getId() == produto.getId()) {
                p.setQuantidade(produto.getQuantidade());
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public List<Produto> getProdutos() {
        return produtos;
    }

    public String toJson() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }
}


ClienteTest.java

package br.com.alura.loja;

import br.com.alura.loja.modelo.Carrinho;
import com.google.gson.*;
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.Client;
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ClienteTest {

    @Test
    public void testaConexaoServidor() {

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8085");
        String conteudo = target.path("/v1/carrinhos").request().get(String.class);

        Carrinho carrinho = (Carrinho) new Gson().fromJson(conteudo); **//Cannot resolve method 'fromJson(java.lang.String)'/**
        System.out.println(carrinho);
        Assert.assertEquals("Rua Vergueiro, 3185", carrinho.getRua());


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```java
> Carrinho carrinho = (Carrinho) new Gson().fromJson(conteudo); **//Cannot resolve method 'fromJson(java.lang.String)'/**
> ```

The reason for this is that there is no `Gson.fromJson(String)` method, see the [`Gson` class documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html). For deserialization Gson needs to know which type you are expecting, so all `fromJson` methods have a second parameter representing the type.

You can simply change your code to:

```java
Carrinho carrinho = new Gson().fromJson(conteudo, Carrinho.class);
```